# How to order a list of different type of question displayed with v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of questions. Each question has an order and a type, for example :

```
{
 "name":  "Text",
 "order": 1,
 "type":  "text"
},
{
 "name":  "Wysiwyg",
 "order": 2,
 "type":  "wysiwyg"
},
{
 "name":  "Table",
 "order": 3,
 "type":  "table"
}
```

In my view, I display the fields and depending on their type, they are different :

```
<el-form-item label="test" 
    :key="question.id"
    v-for="question in questions.questions"
    v-if="question.type == 'text'">
    <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
</el-form-item>

<el-form-item
        :key="question.id"
        v-for="question in questions.questions"
        v-if="question.type == 'wysiwyg'">
        <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
</el-form-item>

<el-form-item
        :key="question.id"
        v-for="question in questions.questions"
        v-if="question.type == 'table'">
        <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

In my json response, I get the questions in the right order.

In my view, if they are all questions of the same type, they are displayed in the correct order.

When these are different types of questions, it no longer takes my exact order and first displays the type of fields that are defined in the order of the HTML code

In my example above, it does not matter if a `wysiwyg` type question should appear before, it will always show the questions of type 'text' first.

How should I go about avoiding this?

EDIT : Following the response of @Terry, I tested. It works halfway. In my fields, I have blocks with text and divs. It duplicates everything. Example :

```
<el-form-item class="u-m-b-0" v-if="question.type == 'table-historique-emplois'">
    <div class="table-3-col__container">
    <div class="table-3-col__title">Année</div>
    <div class="table-3-col__title">Employeur</div>
     <div class="table-3-col__title">Titre de la fonction</div>
     </div>
     <div class="table-3-col__inputs">
     <el-input
            :key="question.id"
            v-model="answers[question.id]"
            class="table-3-col__input"></el-input>
      </div>
    </el-form-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of [@Terry 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576132/2933479) and from what I saw on the comments is this what you want?

```
    <el-form-item label="test" 
        :key="question.id"
        v-for="question in questions.questions">
        <el-input 
             :id="'question_' + question.id" 
             v-model="answers[question.id]"
             v-if="question.type == 'text'">
        </el-input>
        <el-input 
             :id="'question_' + question.id" 
             v-model="answers[question.id]"
             v-if="question.type == 'wysiwyg'">
        </el-input>
        <el-input 
             :id="'question_' + question.id" 
             v-model="answers[question.id]"
             v-if="question.type == 'table'">
        </el-input>
    </el-form-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to simply decouple the `v-for` and the `v-if` bindings, so that you do not rely on the DOM order to display the questions:

```
<template v-for="question in questions.questions">
    <el-form-item label="test" 
        :key="question.id"
        v-if="question.type == 'text'">
        <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>

    <el-form-item label="test" 
        :key="question.id"
        v-if="question.type == 'wysiwyg'">
        <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>

    <el-form-item
        :key="question.id"
        v-if="question.type == 'table'">
        <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello @Terry and thanks! I edited my question, your solution doesn't work because I don't have same structure for all my inputs

Comment: @Jeremy Can you elaborate? It shouldn't matter at all. How you handle each individual item is entirely up to the markup, as long as you partition them into `v-if` blocks individually.

Comment: for some blocks, I would like just itterate in the inputs. No in the div around. In the example I added, it duplicates my entire block. I would only like to duplicate the inputs inside. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

#### First of all i would abstract those subelements into own components.

```
-FormItem
  index.js
  default.vue
  +[type]
    index.vue
```

something like this as the root of the type based dynamic component

```
// index.js

export default {
  props: [
    'type',
    ...
  ],
  cmpt(){
  
    try {
      (() => import(`./${this.type}/index.vue`))()
      return () => import(`./${this.type}/index.vue`);
    } catch {
      return () => import(`./default.vue`);
    }
  },
  render(h){
  
    return h('component', {is: this.cmpt, attrs: this.$attrs })
  }
}
```

and as its usage

```
<FormItem v-for="item in items" :attrs="item" :key="item.id"/>
```

#### no `v-if` as component is chosen by `item.type`